# Reports for java desktop application

Tags: java, netbeans

I am developing an inventory system in java using Netbeans 7.0 IDE. In it I need to print bills now I am wondering how to make them. Please recommend me how to make reports from java desktop application and how to print it eventually. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2):

JasperReports is your friend: http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports

Answer (score 2):

Try [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/), we are using this for printing reports in our java web application. It's really easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void openBrowser(final String url) {
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
 try {
         if (osName.startsWith("Windows"))
                 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                                 "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);

 } catch (Exception ex) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in opening browser"
                         + ":\n" + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
 }

}
```

Try Jasper Reports using this code. just pass  path of report in to function

Comment: how can i pass a value form a jtextbox to a jasper report?

Comment: @NiteshVerma Can You explain me What u need to  do exactly?

Comment: I have a 3 jtextBox with some values on a form. I want to print a report consisting of those values.